# Values less than threshold = 0 more than threshold =1 using r

Tags: r, logistic-regression, data-manipulation

I have a column with values between 0 and 1 and I want to use a threshold, say 0.7. If a value is less than 0.7 I want it to change to 0 and more than 0.7 change to 1.

I need to do this to measure my prediction accuracy since the actual responses are in 0 & 1 format.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also ifelse:

```
df$column <- ifelse(df$column > 0.7, 1, 0)
```

This reads if your variable is greater than 0.7, change to 1 and if it is not, change to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
table$column[table$column<0.7]<- 0
table$column[table$column>0.7]<- 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can coerce the logical vector to binary with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(df$column > 0.7)
```